# how to to send data when tab is selected or swipe?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I make a simple example of tab view using fragment and pager .I want to send to send data from one fragment to another fragment when user use tab button. I will give you more detail I have one list view in one tab . In that i take one array list  to display the data in list view.I want to send that list view in another fragment . So I make one interface and implement it on main activity .But I don’t know how to send on which event  to send fragment .when user select tab I want to send array list to second fragment

here is my code 
**mainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FragmentpagerAdapter fragmentpagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar actionBar =getActionBar();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        fragmentpagerAdapter =new FragmentpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentpagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Stations").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("fav Station").setTabListener(this));

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Fragmentone fragmentOne = (Fragmentone) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager,0));
// get your arraylist using method of FragmentOne
        ArrayList<DataModel> yourArrayList = fragmentOne.getData();

        // refer your second fragment and set the above arraylist in that
        FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 1));
        fragmentTwo.setData(yourArrayList);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
    }

}
```

**fragmentone**

```
public class Fragmentone  extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<DataModel> name;
    boolean isPressed=false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        name=new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        name.add(new DataModel("First Station",false));
        name.add(new DataModel("Second Station",false));





        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter =new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),name);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);




        return view;
    }

    public ArrayList getData() {
        return name;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**FragmentTwo**

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }

    public void methodInFragmentB(ArrayList arrayList){

       for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){

       }

    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<DataModel> yourArrayList){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ArrayList Size: " + yourArrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}
```

**PagerAdaper**

```
public class FragmentpagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public FragmentpagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {

            case 0:
                return new Fragmentone();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            default:
                break;



        }
        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**customAdapater**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    boolean isPressed=false;


    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



    }

    /*********
     * Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements
     *********/
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;

        public ImageButton imageButton;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.station_name);

            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
            holder.imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");

        } else {

            DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) data.get(position);

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText(dataModel.getText());

            // this is for overall row click
            vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("row is click","row click"+position);
                }
            });
            // this is for image button onclick
            holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) data.get(position);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(dataModel.isselected()){
                        holder.imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
                        dataModel.setIsselected(false);
                    }else{
                        holder.imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
                        dataModel.setIsselected(true);
                    }
                    isPressed = !isPressed; // reverse

                }
            });
            ;


        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
   >


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**fragmentone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#325633"
   >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragmenttwo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ee2333">

</LinearLayout>
```

**rowlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/station_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#eee345"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="#00ffffff"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

I need to to send    **ArrayList name;** in second fragment ..I used interface but I don't know on event how to get value of that array list when user swipe or tab on tab view  in second fragment?

Comment: you want to pass data only on Tab click and swipe ? is that so  ?

Comment: yes I want to send data or arraylist on tabclick and swipe

Comment: Then for that actually you will not need an Interface and callback method. For this you  will need to refer to your fragments in your MainActivity by using `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`, create methods in both the fragments and access those methods after you have got reference to your Fragments

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi please give some code

Comment: I will update you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am posting some code that might help, see the scenario is like this,

Your tabs are in your `Activity` so the click and swipe events would be handled there so declaring `Interface` will not help as you can not fire that `Callback` method in `Tab` swipe or click, so what you can do is create a method in `FragmentOne` which will return you `ArrayList` like below

```
public ArrayList<String> getData(){
   return yourArrayList();
}
```

now in `FragmentTwo` create a method that will receive the `ArrayList` from `FragmentOne` like below

```
public void setData(ArrayList<String> yourArrayList){
  Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"ArrayList Size: "+yourArrayList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now about how to reference the `Fragments` in your `Activity` you can do something like this:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
   return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
}
```

Now in `Tab` Swipe or click call above method to Refer your fragments like below

```
ArrayList<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
FragmentOne fragmentOne = getSupportFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(viewPagerId,0))
if(fragmentOne != null){
// get your arraylist using method of FragmentOne
    yourArrayList = fragmentOne.getData();
}
// refer your second fragment and set the above arraylist in that
FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = getSupportFragmentManger().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(viewPagerId,1))
if(fragmentTwo != null){
   fragmentTwo.setData(yourArrayList);
}
```

and you are done

see above 0 and 1 are index of fragments in adapter you will need to manage that
let me know if you need further help

Comment: what is  viewPagerId in this

Comment: `R.id.pager` your viewpager id that you declared in xml

Comment: can I give you code .please look where is doing wrong

Comment: or I will post my whole code here actuallY am getting null pointer exception here in this line fragmentOne.getData();

Comment: see my update ..i am geting exception on this line  fragmentTwo.setData(yourArrayList);

Comment: It did work for me with a minor tweak . see the edit

Answer (score 0):

In your first `fragment` named `Fragmentone`, do something like this:

```
    if(callBack!=null){
     callBack.sendData(yourDataArrayList);
}
```

After doing this see what are you getting in `log`.

Comment: w
here I write this code ? on which method .I want to do this when user switch tabs ..Actually I have tabs in my view ..I think I need to write this onTabselect method

Comment: write it in your Fragmentone after you have added data to your array list.

Comment: yes, if you have to do that then write it in the listening event.

Comment: override those listeners in your Fragmentone.

Comment: how it is possible ? could you please help me

Comment: try and implemet OnTabChangeListener in your Fragmentone and override its onTabChanged() method. See if it works this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88533/discussion-between-kaveesh-kanwal-and-user944513).