# passing data between fragments when swiped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I am newbie to android.I am trying to develop an application which contains a Viewpager with Tabs.My Aim is to pass the data entered in first fragment(i.e tab1) to second fragment.I am confused how to get the data in FragmentA and show it in FragmentB besides my viewpager is in Mainactivity.

some of my code is

```
mviewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+servloc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mviewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
            int index = mviewpager.getCurrentItem();
            if(position==0) {
                Fragmentpageadapter adapter = (Fragmentpageadapter) mviewpager.getAdapter();

                CreateInspectionFragmentA ca= (CreateInspectionFragmentA) adapter.getFragment(index);
            }
```

above code is viewpage setonpagechangelistener..

and my pageadapter is

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
          CreateInspectionFragmentA createInspectionFragmenta=new CreateInspectionFragmentA();
            mPageReferenceMap.put(position, createInspectionFragmenta);
  return createInspectionFragmenta;
        case 1:
            CreateInspectionFragmentB createInspectionFragmentb = new CreateInspectionFragmentB();
          //  createInspectionFragmentb.deliverData(data1,data2);
         mPageReferenceMap.put(position,createInspectionFragmentb);
              return createInspectionFragmentb;

        case 2:
            CreateInspectionFragmentC createInspectionFragmentc = new CreateInspectionFragmentC();
             mPageReferenceMap.put(position,createInspectionFragmentc);
            return createInspectionFragmentc;
        default:
            return null;
    }
   }
```

my requirement is to pass the data i entered in FragmentA in edittext to be seen in FragmentB when swiped but not when button click or something.

posibilities:
1.if there is a way to get the UI controls of FragmentA in onpageselected i can bind the EditText view and get the data.
2. using Bundle.
please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to to send data when tab is selected or swipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344885/how-to-to-send-data-when-tab-is-selected-or-swipe)

Comment: I have answered a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344885/how-to-to-send-data-when-tab-is-selected-or-swipe/32346044#32346044 let us know if you need further assistance

Comment: this did not solve my problem.but thank you for your help.I just need to take value from Edittext in FragmentA and just pass it to Fragment B.Where do you mean me to write getting value from edittext.I am sorry i did not understand.

Comment: in `CreateInspectionFragmentA` `getData()` method return String value from `EditText` and in `CreateInspectionFragmentB` `setData(String value)` method pass that `String` value. Is it clear ?

Comment: You need to call `getData()` and `setData()` method in `onPageSelected()` method

Comment: It is clear to me.Thank you but my actual requirement is not limited for just one field.i have 8 fields which are of different datatypes like some of them are boolean values,some imageviews and spinner value.so i cannot pass all these information in setmethod().

Comment: i am thinking in the way to get the instance of a particular fragment in onpageselected method and access all the UI controls of that fragment.

Comment: you got it good, in order to pass those values create a custom class as per your requirement and do accordingly

Comment: isn't there any chance for us to get the controls somthing like view v=inflator.inflate(R.layout.createinspection_a,null);  and then Edittext et=(EditText)v.findviewbyId(R.id.et1); String name=et.getText().toString();

Comment: so just forget about view v inflate and all..here,i am trying to get instance of a fragment  in onpageselected and through that instance i want to get cotnrol over the UI.you got me?Thanks man.please share your view

Comment: i got it partially,,but can you elaborate "control over UI" ?

Comment: Control over UI means whatever user enters in fragmentA those details or those controls must be accessible in on swiping the viewpager(inActivity).

Comment: As an end result you want data from controls right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. In FragmentA you put this code

```
    private static NameOfTheFragment instance = null;


    public static NameOfTheFragment getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }
```

Then create a function to return what you want, like a List View

```
    public ListView getList(){
       return list; 
    }
```

Then in FragmentB you do this in onCreateView

```
    ListView list = NameOfTheFragment.getInstance().getList();
```

Then you show list in fragment B

Comment: i dont want to use loaders concept man thank you anyway.I want to get the UI control without layoutinflator in onpageselected method.one way i thought is through instance of a fragment .

Comment: I understood ur logic, but i need to get all the data from UI elements  present in Fragment A when i swiped the viewPager, in this case where should i capture the data from the Ui(present in Fragment A). Can u send me the piece of code for the same.

Comment: what kind of data do you want to pass?

Comment: fields data .Okay i have solved the this problem by getting the control of fragment from Activity only.I got the view from the adapter in addonpagechangelistener of viewpager and binded those controls of the view.now,i can pass the data on swipe to the next page.