# get the hidden textview value in fragment from activity onpageselected event android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to get the hidden value which is set in Fragment Page in order to work on it. I am setting the hidden value in Fragment Page and want to get that hidden value in the activity page's Viewpager onPageSelected value in oreder to update the fragment with detail information. Is this possible?

> My Fragment page

```
 public class CountryFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String STARTUP_ID = "startupID";
    private String st_id;

    public CountryFragment() {
            // emtpy
        }
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String st_id = getArguments().getString(STARTUP_ID);
    this.st_id = st_id;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_fragment, container, false);
    TextView hiddenstatupid= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hiddenstatuptextview);
    hiddenstatupid.setText(st_id);
    return v;
    }
}
```

> Activity Page

```
public class IndividualPage extends ActionBarActivity{
ViewPager pager;
@Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
      pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()                {

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //here is where i need to get the hidden id of startup which is in the countryfragment
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

> My CountryPageAdapter

```
public class CountryPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public CountryPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);

    }
}
```

Comment: i have given a answer here you can se the same to acces the hidden value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344885/how-to-to-send-data-when-tab-is-selected-or-swipe/32346044#32346044

Answer (score 0):

Iy your CountryFragment part of the viewpager? If so, then you can have a local store of your fragments in your pager adapter and then get the fragment from the viewpager adapter using the position.

If your adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter you have to implement the getItem() method.

You will have something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        CountryFragment frag = pager.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added code and also checked your line of code .. but i am getting Cannot resolve method on `getItem(position);`

Comment: As I said, your viewpager adapter needs to be a android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Your adapter needs to extend from it. The FragmentStatePagerAdapter has an abstract method getItem().

Comment: not working though change the FragmentPager to FragmentStateAdapter

Comment: Is the fragment part of the viewpager or just the activity?

Comment: And this the adapter has a local fragment store, e.g. a list with fragment and you return them by position.