# getting data from tabs using fragment in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, tabs

i am developing an android app which have a tab activity.in this activity there are four more tabs which is created by using Fragments.now i want to get the data from the fragment tabs in the main tab activity.i searched a lot but not find the exact answer.if any could solve this. below is my code

Main Tab Activity

```
public class TabedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables
    MobileServiceClient MSC;
    MobileServiceTable MST;

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Basic","Education","Profession","Experiance"};
    int Numboftabs =4;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabed);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

      //  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                goToHome();
                return true;
            case R.id.done:
                Toast.makeText(this, "you select done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;



            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }



        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    }
   public  void goToHome(){

       Intent gotohome=new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
       startActivity(gotohome);
   }
    //the following function was added to update but not working

public static void settingValues(){
```

and the Tab activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by hp1 on 21-01-2015.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        EditText contactNumber= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextcontact);
        EditText address= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        contactNumber.setHint("Your ContactNo Plz");
        address.setHint("Your address Plz");

        return v;
    }
}
```

View Page Adapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else if (position==1){

            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }
        else if (position==2){
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        }

        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
          Tab4 tab4=new Tab4();
            return tab4;
        }


    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344885/how-to-to-send-data-when-tab-is-selected-or-swipe/32346044#32346044

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi this is also a great answer but not solved my problem.can you please tell me how can i access the controls of Tab1 in the main activity.for example get the text of EditText and so on.please help

Comment: on what eevent you want to access that data /

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi on onOptionsItemSelected in the Main tabbed activity.

Comment: then in that method get a reference to your fragment as i did in the link and then get data from there, i will post an answer if you want

Comment: You are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, try using `FragmentPagerAdapter` and as in the answer i have given previously just get a reference to the `fragment` using proper `index` i.e **0,1,2,3** get the data you want

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi please post an answer if possible because i m not able to get reference in that method.i.e in main tabd activity.

Comment: Are you going to have a fixed number of tabs ? if so then use `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: ok i replace FragmentStatePagerAdapter with FragmentPagerAdapter .now where i can set the fragment index ie 0,1,2,3 and then how can i get the reference in the main tabed activity.please

Comment: just a minute posting a answer see if this helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93754/discussion-between-user3470010-and-satyen-udeshi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
In order get reference to your views you should declare that `view(s)` at `class` level for e.g

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

EditTex address,contactNumber;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

    contactNumber= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextcontact);
    address= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    contactNumber.setHint("Your ContactNo Plz");
    address.setHint("Your address Plz");

    return v;
   }

   public String getData(){
        return address.getText().toString();
   }
}
```

First declare a global variable to maintain reference to `currentPage` being displayed

`int currentPage = 0;` // 0 - because initially 0th page is displayed.

You can get reference to your  `Fragment` using the following method:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
  return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
}
```

in the above `viewPagerId` is your `ViewPager's` `id`

You will need to keep a reference for the `current page` being displayed for this `implement addOnPageChangeListener()` on `ViewPager` and in `onPageSelected()` method update your `currentPage` variable.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Now in order to get data in `onOptionsItemSelected()` method you can do like below

```
// You will need to check for the index manually and get the reference of the current `Fragment` so a solution to this can be like 

if(currentPage == 0){
   Tab1 tab1 = (Tab1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.your_view_pager,currentPage));
   // always check for null
   if(tab1 != null){
      String data = tab1.getData();
   }
}else if(currentPage == 1){
   Tab2 tab2 =    (Tab2)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.your_view_pager,currentPage));

   if(tab2 != null){
      String data = tab2.getData();
   }
}

... so on
```

create method in your fragments to access the data for e.g

```
public String getData(){
    String data = yourEditText.getText().toString();
    return data;
}
```

similarly you can access other data as well, let me know if you require more details

Comment: one last question how you find this statment.   public String getData(){
    String data = yourEditText.getText().toString();
    return data;
}

Comment: here i can not get reference to the editText .check it if possible.thnks

Comment: You will need to declare `EditText` outside of `onCreateView()`

Comment: will you elaborate with an example please

Comment: creating null pointer exception  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93765/discussion-between-satyen-udeshi-and-user3470010).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93766/discussion-between-immi-khan-and-satyen-udeshi).

Comment: still in problem i will send you all the code of this activity if you can solve it .my email is iammswt@gmail.com please send  an email so that i can send the code.thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is nothing but the `nested fragment` basically fragment inside fragment(nesting) is `not supported`.your doing the same, `Nested fragments are not currently supported`. Trying to put a fragment within the UI of another fragment will result in undefined and likely broken behavior of the app..

Comment: its working fine but the problem is that i cannot access the elements of Tab1 fragment.ie.textview and Edit Text..i only want to access these elements from the main TabedActivity .